# Expected Value of a Fundraiser Raffle Ticket with Three Prizes

Tags: probability, expected-value, combinatorics, games

[image: Lottery Details]

The raffle ticket above represents a local fundraiser. The first prize is a smart TV valued at 1200 dollars, the second prize is a cooler valued at 200 dollars, and the third prize is a 100 dollar cash prize. The third prize will be picked first, then the second, and the first prize (TV) will be picked last to build suspense.

1. What is the number of tickets bought that would maximize the expected value?

I suspect the expected value function will depend on the number of tickets purchased by you and the number of tickets purchased by others. We can assume a fixed number of tickets sold (say 100 tickets sold in total) to the problem. I have built a tree diagram (see below) to calculate the probabilities. Sorry for the poor writing (broken hand).
[image: Tree Diagran]

In the tree diagram. I used T to represent the number of tickets you purchased and N to represent the total number of tickets purchased. I have also built a [Desmos file](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mtrikcqbbd) to try to play around with the values and calculate the probabilities. I think I got the probabilities down pat but I am now sure how to calculate the expected value as a function of the number of tickets purchased.

I also just plotted it in 3D as a function of 2 variables using [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/sjuxesye).

Thanks for the help!

Comment: As you note immediately after stating your question (1), it is ill posed: the expected value depends on *two* quantities, not one, and so the answer cannot possibly be phrased only in terms of "*the* number of tickets bought."  Indeed, isn't the solution obvious? You maximize *your* expectation by buying three tickets and preventing anyone else from buying any.

Comment: @whuber Let's assume that they only printed 100 tickets. You can pick any number. That is why I built it in desmos [link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mtrikcqbbd) so I can vary the Total number of tickets sold. Buying three tickets would not prevent the others from purchasing the other 97.

Comment: Then you need to add that information to your post.  But since the expected value of one raffle ticket is $\$15$ and you pay $\$20$ for each one, the obvious solution is to buy no tickets.  What rules out this solution?